# Refactor states with hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to refactor simply code with hardcoded initial state, but I am new to React Hooks.

```
const TimersDashboard = () => {
  const [timers, timersChange] = useState(0)


  React.state = {
    timers: [
      {
        id: UUID.v4(),
        activity: 'Testing activity',
        description: 'Lorem ipsum kraf maga',
        elapsed: '0',
        runningSince: Date.now(),
      },
      {
        id: UUID.v4(),
        activity: 'Next activity',
        description: 'Lorem ipsum kung fu',
        elapsed: '0',
        runningSince: Date.now(),
      }
    ]
  }

  return (
    <div className='ui three column centered grid'>
      <div className='column'>
        <TimersList
          timers={this.state.timers} 
        />
        <NewTimerTool
          isOpen={false}
        />
      </div>    
    </div>
  );
}
```

I have problem to rewrite initial state with Hooks.

Answer (score 2):

You are using a functional component u can only use Hooks. React.state is only for class components.
If you want your intial React.state initialize it like this

```
const [timers, setTimers] = useState([
  {
    id: UUID.v4(),
    activity: "Testing activity",
    description: "Lorem ipsum kraf maga",
    elapsed: "0",
    runningSince: Date.now(),
  },
  {
    id: UUID.v4(),
    activity: "Next activity",
    description: "Lorem ipsum kung fu",
    elapsed: "0",
    runningSince: Date.now(),
  },
]);
```

In TimersList just get the values of the useState like this  `<TimersList timers={timers}/>`.

Comment: Oh, thats it! Thank you!

Comment: Consider accepting my answer if it helped you.